# Logging PHP notice errors

Tags: php, logging, e-notices

I have recently taken over development of a legacy system and want to be able to turn on logging of PHP `E_NOTICE`'s on the deployment environment. The deployment environment ini has the following directives...

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
display_errors = Off
log_errors = On
```

I have compared the `error_reporting` bitmask by using `echo (E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED).' = '.error_reporting();`, and both match, so I know the `error_reporting` level isn't changed within the system itself, and if I turn `display_errors = On` notices are displayed, but not logged.

So how can I start logging PHP `E_NOTICE`'s?

Comment: See this:
http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it should be logging notices already. Have you checked whether it's using some custom error handler?

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario - my thoughts exactly. There is no custom error handler, when I turn on displaying of errors (display_errors = On), notices are displayed, but not logged!

Comment: Just to start narrowing the issue, you could forget the actual code base and try [this simple snippet](http://pastebin.com/6NCRcaUd).

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario - that snippet doesn't log anything at all, no file 'foo.log' is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the system has a custom Apache `ErrorLog` directive defined, and I have been `tail -f ...` the default Apache error_log.

*Note to self: always check the web server setup first before posting silly questions on SO!*

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

According to @m.p.c in the comments on this answer, errors are being displayed in the browser when `display_errors` is on, but they aren't appearing in the log. I was assuming errors weren't appearing at all.

Are `E_NOTICE` errors the only ones that aren't appearing in the log, or are all error types affected? If it's all error types, then the first thing I would check is whether or not error logging is even enabled. Try setting `ini_set('log_errors', 'On');` at the top of your script. If that doesn't work, then try setting your log file to something you're *sure* your server can write to by calling `ini_set('error_log', 'your_file_path');`. If neither of these work, then I think something is seriously wrong with your PHP install. If either of these fixes work, you can put them into your actual `php.ini` if you have access.

---

**Original Answer:**

Based on the `error_reporting` level in your question, your PHP install should already be setup to report `E_NOTICE` errors. If it's not logging these errors, something is wrong. I would suggest turning on `display_errors` to see if any `E_NOTICE` errors are displayed. If you can't change the `php.ini` file, try running `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` at the top of your script. Obviously, these errors will only show up and/or be logged if you trigger one, so you should double check that you're actually doing that somewhere.

One caveat is that the `E_DEPRECATED` error level was only introduced with PHP 5.3. When I just tested setting `E_DEPRECATED` on a PHP 5.2 install, PHP responded with errors, and set the `error_reporting` level to `0`, which means it reports *no errors at all*. While it makes no sense for a pre-5.3 `php.ini` file to use this setting, I feel it's important to at least raise the possibility that you're using `E_DEPRECATED` on a server that doesn't support it. If you're not sure of your version, you can run `phpinfo()` and it will display a page with lots and lots of information, including the version number for your install.

Notwithstanding the above, if I've misunderstood your question and you're only talking about creating your own custom logging, then you need to create a function to run when an error occurs and assign it as the error handler using the `set_error_handler()` function.

It's important to note that when you use `set_error_handler()`, you bypass PHP's default error handler entirely. This means that your `error_handler` level becomes meaningless. All errors, regardless of their severity, will be passed to the error handler function you've created. The first parameter passed to this function by PHP will be the error number, which is the numeric value of the `E_xxx` constant of the error that was found. You'll need to write custom code to catch only the errors you want.

For example, to catch *only* `E_NOTICE` errors, your function would look like this:

```
function my_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
  if ($errno == E_NOTICE) {
    // handle/log the error
  } 
}

set_error_handler("my_error_handler");
```

Comment: A thorough and well constructed answer. However, turning on display_errors does show notices, they are just not logged, and the server is running PHP 5.3.5, so the E_DEPRECATED issue is not applicable. I'd like to avoid writing my own error handler, I just can't work out why notices will display, but won't log!

Comment: @m.p.c I didn't realize these errors were displaying in the browser. It seems like your `error_reporting` levels are fine, and its the log file itself that's having an issue. I've made an update at the top of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own handler

```
<?php


function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if ($errno == E_USER_NOTICE){
        /*  log actions here */
    }
}

set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid adding a custom error handler, this doesn't solve the problem of notices displaying when I turn on display_errors = On, but still not logging.